# Python sort order unicode/ansi differs

Tags: python, python-2.7, localization

I get this strange behavior:

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf-8')
'de_DE.utf-8'
>>> sorted([u'<NULL', u'NULL>', u'<NULL>', u'NULL', u'a'], cmp=locale.strcoll)
[u'a', u'<NULL', u'<NULL>', u'NULL', u'NULL>']
>>> sorted(['<NULL', 'NULL>', '<NULL>', 'NULL', 'a'], cmp=locale.strcoll)
['a', 'NULL', 'NULL>', '<NULL', '<NULL>']
```

While is is OK to sort "<NULL" after "a", what bothers me is that for unicode "<NULL" < "NULL" while with ANSI "NULL" < "<NULL", though the collation is the same.

Is there a way to work around this?

Update: PyICU gives a result, that differs from both of the above.

```
>>> import PyICU
collator = PyICU.Collator.createInstance(PyICU.Locale('de_DE.UTF-8'))
>>> sorted([u'<NULL', u'NULL>', u'<NULL>', u'NULL', u'a'], cmp=collator.compare)
[u'<NULL', u'<NULL>', u'a', u'NULL', u'NULL>']
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce using your exact code with CPython 2.7.3 on OS/X.

Comment: I use Python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.10, but my colleague can reproduce it on RedHat, too.

Do you use the de_DE locale? What are your results?

Comment: Yes, I set the same locale and in the question. I get `['<NULL', '<NULL>', 'NULL', 'NULL>', 'a']` and `[u'<NULL', u'<NULL>', u'NULL', u'NULL>', u'a']`.

Comment: Hmmm. 'NULL' before 'a' is not correct German sorting, looks more  like the C locale.

Comment: And yet this is what happens when I copy and paste your code (including the `locale.setlocale()` call) into my Python shell.

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce your results on Mac OS X, too. Very weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to always use unicode(or the byte strings) as key:

```
import locale
from functools import cmp_to_key

@cmp_to_key
def strcoll(a, b):
    if isinstance(a, str):
        a = a.decode('utf-8')
    if isinstance(b, str):
        b = b.decode('utf-8')
    return locale.strcoll(a, b)
```

Then the following should give the same output:

```
sorted([u'<NULL', u'NULL>', u'<NULL>', u'NULL', u'a'], key=strcoll)
sorted(['<NULL', 'NULL>', '<NULL>', 'NULL', 'a'], key=strcoll)
```

I'd use `key` instead of `cmp` since it is more portable.

An even simpler approach is to simply keep all the strings as unicodes/bytes explcitly:

```
def to_unicode(s):
    return s.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(s, str) else s

the_list = [...]
the_list = [to_unicode(elem) for elem in the_list]
```

This approach has the advantage of doing a single conversion between `str` and `unicode`, while the other approach does a conversion per comparison(even using `key` and `cmp_to_key`).

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to use a German locale other than de_DE.utf-8. Funnily it works with for example de_AT.utf-8.

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf-8')
'en_US.utf-8'
>>> sorted([u'<NULL', u'NULL>', u'<NULL>', u'NULL', u'a'], cmp=locale.strcoll)
[u'a', u'NULL', u'<NULL', u'<NULL>', u'NULL>']
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_AT.utf-8')
'de_AT.utf-8'
>>> sorted([u'<NULL', u'NULL>', u'<NULL>', u'NULL', u'a'], cmp=locale.strcoll)
[u'a', u'NULL', u'<NULL', u'<NULL>', u'NULL>']
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_CH.utf-8')
'de_CH.utf-8'
>>> sorted([u'<NULL', u'NULL>', u'<NULL>', u'NULL', u'a'], cmp=locale.strcoll)
[u'a', u'NULL', u'<NULL', u'<NULL>', u'NULL>']
```

But:

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf-8')
'de_DE.utf-8'
>>> sorted([u'<NULL', u'NULL>', u'<NULL>', u'NULL', u'a'], cmp=locale.strcoll)
[u'a', u'<NULL', u'<NULL>', u'NULL', u'NULL>']
```

This narrows it down to a bug with the German main locale on some Linux system, I guess.